# MVC vNext Routing and ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core

**MVC 6 - vNext with Core 5.0**

I am using a route in my project, this looks like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    template: "{firstId}/{secondId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Window", action = "Index" });
```

In one of my Views I try to create an `ActionLink` like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Title", "Index", "Window", new { firstId = "a", secondId = "b" }, null);
```

This `ActionLink` returns the following anchor:

```
<a href="/Window?firstId=a&secondId=b">Test</a>
```

But what I'm expecting is:

```
<a href="/a/b">Test</a>
```

Can anyone clear this up?

Comment: Is that your only route?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Yes, this is my only route.

Comment: I don't see how that's possible if that's your only route.  You should be getting a 404 if the route doesn't match.  Do you not even have a default route?

Comment: @TheOddGuy What is `template`? Shouldn't that be `url`

Comment: @jumpingcode http://i.gyazo.com/d18674e5d6291380322573cc25fb3e9c.png

Comment: @TheOddGuy Since you're using MVC6, are there any Route Attributes?

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue may just be that you are using `template` property instead of `url`. Having looked at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.route_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) I couldn't find a `template` property on the `Route` class, are you implementing your own?

In any case I think this should work (providing you have no other routes defined as you've said):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{firstId}/{secondId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Window", action = "Index" }
);
```

Comment: Intellisense shows 'template' and not 'url'. Maybe because I'm using MVC 6 (see: http://i.gyazo.com/d18674e5d6291380322573cc25fb3e9c.png)

When I visit 'a/b' manually (via url) it seems working.

Comment: @TheOddGuy yeah that's kinda a big thing. Might be worth editing your question

Comment: @jumpingcode Yes, my fault I guess since I'm new to MVC :-) Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you show your whole route setup? Since you are saying that in one of your views you are doing something else I'm assuming you must have reached it through another action and hence another route ...

Aside: Consider using attribute routes (they are on by default) so you can decorate your action with [HttpGet("{firstId}/{secondId}"] and you are done, no need for defaults etc.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the route:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
     "Default",
     "Window/Index/{firstId}/{secondId}",
     new { controller = "Window", action = "Index" });
```

Which will yield the following:

```
<a href="Window/Index/a/b">Test</a>
```

Comment: Solved my own issue with answer formats, so revised my comment.

Comment: In the question you ask for a route: `/a/b` yet your answer renders `window/index/a/b`. I think if you look at my comment on your question, it will remove the `window/index`

Comment: @jumpingcode I guess in the future I need to first double check with the original poster to ensure the only correct answer is a/b vs him simply being confused?  Will that prevent your downvote?

Comment: Well your answer is incorrect...so when it's correct I'll vote up. Generally how things work.

Comment: @jumpingcode what do you mean by "if you look at my comment on your question"?  I didn't have a question did I?

Comment: Apologies, I thought you were OP for some reason.